# On which level to scale predictors in a multi-level / panel model?

Tags: regression, panel-data, standardization

I am working on a multi-level model that can be simplified to the following equation, where I have the levels organization ($i$), country ($j$) and year ($t$) :

$$
Y_{ijt} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_j + \beta_2 X_t + \beta_3 X_i + \beta_4 X_{jt} + \epsilon.
$$

I am mainly interested in $\beta_1$ and all other predictors are control variables for year (a set of dummies for all years), organization (organizational characteristics) and country-year (time-variant country characteristics). Obviously, the resolution of the data is not ideal: the variables $X_j$ I am interested in are only measured time-invariant and only on the country level, but this limitation cannot be resolved. The panel is also unbalanced.

My problem is that I am unsure on which level to scale / standardize $X_j$ by building z-scores. I see two options:

- Scale across all observations that go into the modelling process, with the result that z-scores of $X_j$ are influenced by how many observations on the level $i$ there are per country $j$ (number of observations is strongly unbalanced and varies across specifications)
- Scale across countries only to maintain that distances between z-scores are only affected by between-country variation.

How will I end up with coefficients that are well interpretable and accurately reflect between-country variation? 
Thanks a lot.